# Recursive call has finish in a function but continue printing integers

Tags: java, recursion, methods, while-loop

I tried to investigate what will happen if I write some code after the recursive call and here is the code. I tried to trace the code but I didn't get what was going on. I thought the function will be terminated once my program prints the last value for x since the value for x doesn't satisfy the if loop condition. I executed this code, the result wasn't understandable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Recursive {

    public static void main(String []args){
        int a=5;
        call(a);
    }

    public static void call(int x) {
        System.out.print(x+"\n");
        if(x>0) {
            x--;
            call(x);
        }
        System.out.print(x);
     }
}
```

Expected output:`5 4 3 2 1 0 0`

My output: `5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 4`

Comment: why do you say the program doesnt terminate? it should terminate very well. Albeit, unexpected prints, but it should terminate from what is in the question

Comment: Time for pencil and paper tracing!

Comment: You should show us your **expected output**, and your current **program output**. Your situation was like, you saw a flying unicorn, and you are questioning _"why does that unicorn fly?"_ instead of _"wow, now I know that unicorn can fly"_ ..just an analogy

Comment: I was expecting output to be something like 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 The program output was 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 1):

instead of while, you can try If condition and remove the last print.

```
public static void call(int x) {
   System.out.print(x+"\n");

   if (x>0) {
      x--;
      call(x--);
   }
}
```

Comment: I replace the while with if. And, I add a System.out.print(x) after the if loop. There were some pattern in the result. Im just wondering why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to say what was surprising or confusing, which indicates that you don't understand the problem (hence two downvotes). Here is what I think may be confusing. The decrement operator `x--` first returns the value of a variable and *then* lowers it's value. So if you run

```
 z= 25
 dothedoo(z--)
```

the value *inside* dothedoo will be 25, not 24. The alternative --x will lower the value  *first* and then return the value.

Comment: The issue isnt the x-- the issue is the pass by value in the recursive call and the understanding of recursion in this case. I think its a bit harsh for 2 downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code.

```
   public static void call(int x) {
      System.out.print(x + "\n");
      while (x > 0) {
         x--;
         call(x);
      }
   }
```

Lets consider this call stack with an input of x=2

> - 1) call(2)
> - 2) print x  // 2
> - 2) x-- (becomes 1)
> - 3) recursive call to call(1) // remember the call(2) is suspended    right now.
> - 4) print x //1
> - 5) x -- (becomes 0)
> - 6) recursive call to call(0)// remember the call(2) and call(1) is    suspended right now.
> - 7) print x //0
> - 8) x-- (becomes -1)
> - 9) recursive call to call(-1) // breaks the loop since it doesnt    match the condition, resumes flow to the suspended call(1) function.
> - 10) refer step 5 for the value of x.
> - 11) breaks the loop for the call(1) function. // resumes call(2)    which was suspended.
> - 12) refer step 2 where x is still 1.
> - 13) moves on with another call(1)
> - 14) this results in printing an extra 0; from the call in step 13

Your while loop is messing up the program.

> Your variable in the recursion is passed by value, hence your actual
>       value of x which is caller's value isnt decremented globally in the caller when you do this `call(x)` the x which is used after
>   decrementing in your recursive call is a copy of the x that you have
>   decremented in the caller.
>
> Please refer to this [article](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) to understand more on it.

Also, the `while loop` is notorious here based on the explaination provided in this answer and what you actuall need is an `if loop`

Comment: Wow, thank you man, you are the guy who actually answered my question, I would vote u up if I can. Another question, What do you mean by call(x) is suspended and why did it resume back to the call? Is that normal in java? or its because I have the while loop

Comment: well, it is normal in java or for that matter in any other language unless you are using threads. When you call function a() from function b(), the execution will wait for function a() to finish its task for function b() to resume its execution. I dont see the tick mark under my answer if i did answer your question ;) :-D lol.